# How to uplaod high quality image to imageview in android?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, image-uploading

I want to upload the high quality image to server and get it in Imageview in my app. I'm able to do so. But the problem is quality of image which is very low. How can i upload the desire resolution of image to server and get it in imageview. Help me. Thanks

Here is my Code:

```
  public class ChangeProfileActivity extends Activity {

  ImageView updateBT, IV;
  private SharedPreferences saveImagePref;
  private SharedPreferences.Editor saveImagePrefEditor;

  protected static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 0;
  protected static final int GALLERY_PICTURE = 1;
  private Intent pictureActionIntent = null;
  Bitmap bitmap;
  private TouchImageView touch;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  // setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_profile);

  updateBT = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);

  dialog = new AlertDialogCheck(ChangeProfileActivity.this);
  IV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.PersonalPictureIV);
  saveImagePref = getSharedPreferences("saveImage", MODE_PRIVATE);
  saveImagePrefEditor = saveImagePref.edit();
  saveDOBPref = getSharedPreferences("saveImage", MODE_PRIVATE);
  saveDOBPrefEditor = saveImagePref.edit();
  registerForContextMenu(IV);

  A = saveImagePref.getString("SAVE", "0");
  bitmap = StringToBitMap(A);
  if (bitmap != null) {
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 250, 250, false);
    IV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  }

  if (bitmap == null) {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
            R.drawable.user_profile_image);
    IV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    IV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            startDialog();
            uploadImage();
        }
    });
  }

  IV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startDialog();
    }
});

  public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  }

  private void startDialog() {
  AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  myAlertDialog.setTitle("Upload Pictures Option");
  myAlertDialog.setMessage("How do you want to set your picture?");

  myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Gallery",
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                pictureActionIntent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
                pictureActionIntent.setType("image/*");
                pictureActionIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent,
                        GALLERY_PICTURE);
            }
        });

  myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Camera",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                pictureActionIntent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent,
                        CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });
 myAlertDialog.show();
 }

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICTURE) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            // our BitmapDrawable for the thumbnail
            BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = null;
            // try to retrieve the image using the data from the intent
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(data.getData(),
                    null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {

                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ImageColumns.DATA);
                String fileSrc = cursor.getString(idx);

                BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
                   options.inSampleSize=1;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileSrc);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 250, 250,
                        true);
                saveImagePrefEditor.clear();
                saveImagePrefEditor.commit();
                saveImagePrefEditor.putString("SAVE",
                        BitMapToString(bitmap));
                saveImagePrefEditor.commit();

                IV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                // touch.setImageBitmap(bitmap);+
                A = saveImagePref.getString("SAVE", "0");
                uploadImage();
            } else {

                bmpDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), data
                        .getData().getPath());
                IV.setImageDrawable(bmpDrawable);
                // touch.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                A = saveImagePref.getString("SAVE", "0");
                uploadImage();
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data.hasExtra("data")) {

            bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 250, 250, false);
            saveImagePrefEditor.clear();
            saveImagePrefEditor.commit();
            saveImagePrefEditor.putString("SAVE",
                    BitMapToString(bitmap));
            saveImagePrefEditor.commit();
            // update the image view with the bitmap
            IV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            // touch.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            A = saveImagePref.getString("SAVE", "0");
            uploadImage();
        } else if (data.getExtras() == null) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No extras to retrieve!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

            BitmapDrawable thumbnail = new BitmapDrawable(
                    getResources(), data.getData().getPath());

            // update the image view with the newly created drawable
            IV.setImageDrawable(thumbnail);
            // touch.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            A = saveImagePref.getString("SAVE", "0");
            uploadImage();
        }

    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }   }
  }

 public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap) {
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
   byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
   String temp = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return temp;
   }

  public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString) {
    try {
    byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0,
            encodeByte.length);
    return bitmap;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.getMessage();
    return null;
}}
}
```

Comment: You need to scale your bitmap using `BitmapFactory.Options` and apply `inSampleSize` for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use android best practice.

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize( 
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image 
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both 
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width. 
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        } 
    } 

    return inSampleSize;
}



public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions 
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize 
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set 
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

public static Bitmap decodeFile(int width , int height ,File f) {
            try {
                // decode image size
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);
                // decode with inSampleSize
                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(o, width, height);
                //System.out.println("Scale: " + scale);
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                //System.out.println("--- exception "+e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```